# Wordpress users to pay to publish post

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway

There's this wordpress theme I'm working on. I have a user role titled "professionals". I want users assigned this role to be able to publish posts if only they have paid or subscribed. I will like to integrate PayPal or any good payment processor to handle payments. How can I achieve this?

I will appreciate if you can recommend link(s) or plugin(s) that could help achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce is a very popular plugin for payment processing and has a subscription service style payment too. You could integrate this into your site and then use a simple conditional statement to see if they are a subscriber and if not send them to the signup page.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.